# UINavigationController clear background color

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

That simple example but that don't work;

I have ViewController where inside on NavigationConroller, then I want to add new ViewConroller with its self navigation controller.

In main viewController:

```
CustomViewController *vc = [[CustomViewController alloc] init];
NewNavigationVC *nav = [[NewNavigationVC alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];

[self presentViewController:nav animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Two controllers has a background color clear, but still black color.
Navigation bar I can do clear, but not a view.

**UPDATE:**

if i change self.window.backroundColor to red for example, that work but not clear

**UPDATE 2:**

```
[self addChildViewController:vc];  
[self.view addSubview:vc.view];
[vc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

and when I want to dealloc vc

```
[vc willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[vc.view removeFromSuperview];
[vc removeFromParentViewController];
```

All work ok without navigation controller

Answer (score 2):

A viewController's view's backgroundColor can't be clear (as in showing the previous viewController's view on the stack). Pushing or presenting a viewController will put the new viewController on the stack and hide the previous viewController completely.

If you want a clear backgroundColor on the view, you will need to either:

1) set the viewController as a childViewController of the previous viewController - then animate the transition yourself.

Or

2) transplant the viewController logic into the previous viewController and have a new uiview act as that view (you also need to animated the transition yourself).

Comment: Yeah that looks good, you'll want to set the vc.view.frame to fit underneath the searchbar before you addSubview, or set the frame in the didMoveToParentViewController method of the childViewController. You'll probably want to put your animations in the didMoveToParentViewController as well.

Comment: @Vadoff can you cite a source for this? This *sounds* right but I can't find documentation proving or disproving this.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is as follows. For clear example we use tableViewController:

```
UITableViewController *modalVC = [UITableViewController new];
UINavigationController *modalNVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:modalVC];

UIViewController *mainVC = [UIViewController new];
UINavigationController *mainNVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainVC];

modalVC.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
mainVC.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor;
mainNVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
[mainNVC presentViewController:modalNVC animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

The key feature is that you have to set `modalPresentationStyle` of presentingViewController to `UIModalPresentationCurrentContext`.

It works fine BUT without slide animation. You will get result immediately.
But you can still use "blood hack" to retain visual animation by successive presenting, dismissing and presenting again:

```
modalVC.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
mainVC.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor;

[mainNVC presentViewController:modalNVC animated:YES completion:^{
    [modalNVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
        mainNVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
        [mainNVC presentViewController:modalNVC animated:NO completion:NULL];
    }];
}];
```

Comment: You can set the presentation transition mode using modalTransitionStyle, or create your own. The last part of your code will expose you to problems in the long term.

Comment: @PeterSuwara It is very old solution to overcome bugs of the old iOS version. Now it works good enough without the second part.

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to tell the navigation controller [to](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimodalpresentationstyle/overcurrentcontext):

```
navigation.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
```

In other words:

> A presentation style where the content is displayed over another view controller’s content.

and that's it.

You can also make sure that:

```
navigation.view.backgroundColor = .clear
```